# How to dropdown selected after data fetched

Tags: php

I want make option selected in dropdown html form, i am fetching data from database but into the html select cant get how to option selected
Below is the My database table data get. from that account holder is the my database value. I want to compare with select option nd make then selected into dropdown.

```
Array
(
    [ipsf_public_pf_id] => 62
    [ipsf_main_id] => 216
    [account_no] => 54545455
    [account_holder] => self
    [pf_amt] => 1500.00
    [date_of_payment] => 2020-11-15
)
```

and my html php form like  this

```
$str .='<input type="hidden" name="ipsf_public_pf_id" value="<?php echo $ipsf_public_pf; ?>">
                        <table align="center" cellspacing="1" class="table table-bordered">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>PPF A/c No</td>
                                    <td>Account Holder</td>
                                    <td>Date of Payment</td>
                                    <td>Amount</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <input name="account_no_'.$ppf.'" type="text" id="account_no_'.$ppf.'" value="'.$account_no.'" size="20" maxlength="20"  class="form-control" onkeyup="Validate_number(this)"/>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <select name="account_holder_'.$ppf.'" id="account_holder_'.$ppf.'" class="form-control">
                                            <option value="" selected>Account Holder</option>
                                            <option value="self">Self</option>
                                            <option value="spouse">Spouse</option>
                                            <option value="children">Children</option>
                                        <!--<option value="others">Others</option>-->
                                        </select>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input name="date_of_payment_date_'.$ppf.'" id="date_of_payment_date_'.$ppf.'" maxlength="2" style="width: 50px;" type="text" onClick="this.value="";" value="'.$date.'"  class="form-control-date" onkeyup="Validate_number(this)"/>-<input name="date_of_payment_month_'.$ppf.'" id="date_of_payment_month_'.$ppf.'" maxlength="2" style="width: 50px;" type="text" onClick="this.value="";" value="'.$month.'"  class="form-control-date" onkeyup="Validate_number(this)"/>-<input name="date_of_payment_year_'.$ppf.'" id="date_of_payment_year_'.$ppf.'" maxlength="4" style="width: 65px;" type="text" onClick="this.value="";" value="'.$year.'" class="form-control-date" onkeyup="Validate_number(this)"/>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>

                                    <input name="ppf_amt_'.$ppf.'" type="text" id="ppf_amt_'.$ppf.'"  value="'.$pf_amt.'" size="10"  onBlur="javascript:increment_ppf_amnt(this.value, '.$ppf.');" maxlength="14" class="form-control-date" onkeyup="Validate_number(this)"/>
                                    
                                    <input type="hidden" name="prev_ppf_amount_'.$ppf.'" id="prev_ppf_amount_'.$ppf.'" value="'.$ppf.'"/>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="is_added_0" id="is_added_0" value="no"/>
                                    
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                
                            </tbody>
                            <input type="hidden" name="total_ppf_amount" id="total_ppf_amount" value="0"/>
                        </table>';
```

I am confused how to selected that option inside .

Anyone know then please help me

Answer (score 0):

On your html just fill the `selected="<?=$selectedOption;?>`.

Basically the logic behind it is: you fetch the data  that you want to, and the values thaty ou on `option` tags you will gonna use the selected id / value or whatever that you want to use for in the `selected atrribute on the <select></<select>` html tag.

Comment: I am not getting you . Actually my html inside one variable.

Comment: What you didn't understand?

Comment: Hoew to campare value with dropdown and make selected . Please see my code inside string. this is my dropdown  .<select name="account_holder_'.$ppf.'" id="account_holder_'.$ppf.'" class="form-control">
                                            <option value="" selected>Account Holder</option>
                                            <option value="self">Self</option>
                                            <option value="spouse">Spouse</option>
                                            <option value="children">Children</option>

Comment: And my answer make that clear, the select it's a html object which has a attribute called select, did you know html as well?

Comment: Still not getting how to set inside html selected that value